# Exporting skeletal mesh to fbx splits many bones into a bone and an "end", increasing the bone count

Tags: export

I have been trying to get meshes from Blender 2.82 into UDK 3, then from there using the models to mod games.  This is turning out to be impossible because when I export fbx (exporting to psk is no longer supported but is better for UDK 3) it takes a model with 42 bones and creates an fbx that has 67 bones (all the additional "bones" are bone ends that do nothing). These extra bones cannot be removed in UDK (apparently) and it makes it impossible to use the model (upk file) in any game because the bone count is wrong. How does one export to fbx without adding fake bones (the bone ends) to the final skeletal mesh?  This didn't used to happen with 2.7x and before.

Comment: I have been able to delete the extra "ghost bones" added by fbx export in Blender by re-importing the fbx file and getting rid of them in edit mode, however, there is still ONE additional bone that I cannot eliminate but I do not know if this is part of how Blender 2.8x now works or if it is fbx. The armature name itself that contains all the bones is being counted as a bone by UDK when the fbx is imported into it.

Comment: PSK exporting is possible with [this plugin](https://github.com/DarklightGames/io_export_psk_psa).